# Child thread access stack of parent thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, callback

I have a question about multithreads in C++. It is my first time using callback. Please forgive me if they are silly questions.

Assume I have two classes, one is a cache, the other is going to use the cache.

```
class Cache
{
public:
    Refresh(){do something with _myCache}
private:
    std::map<...> _myCache;
}
//Then I have another Class
class Processor
{
public:
    Processor(){
        bindToAThread(Cache::Refresh());
        put it into a threadpool
    }
private:
    Cache cache;
}
```

Forgive me about the syntax.

My friend told me that when Refresh() got run, it will operate on the same copy of _myCache to the main thread.

I don't quite understand. Can child threads access stack of its parent thread? I thought threads in the same process share only the heap but not the stack.

Can anyone please tell me why?

If not, can some one please tell me how to do it? Start a child thread to modify something in the main thread.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: C++ has std;;thread - use it to start threads.  One or more threads can exist in a single 'memory space'.  Processes (perhaps a unix or linux term) exist in a single memory space.  The term memory space (IMHO) implies isolation from other processes.  Every linux process contains 1  (main) or more threads.   In Ubuntu 15.10 (64) every thread gets the default 8 MBytes of stack.  A std::threads can be started with a pointer (or reference) to data objects created (and perhaps shared) by other threads, in stack or heap.

Comment: Threads share the heap and have different stacks, but there is nothing preventing one thread looking into another thread's stack if it knows where to look. This makes sharing information very easy and a rogue pointer an absolute pain. Crom only knows which thread it lives in.

Comment: Please review [MCVE].